# How to send an Activity as parameter to a method?

Tags: android

Here I have a method to start differend activities

```
public void StartViewActivities(View view, AppCompatActivity activity)
    {
        ViewGroup selectedGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        NoteObject objectForIntent = new NoteObject();
        objectForIntent.keywords = (String)((TextView)selectedGroup.getChildAt(0)).getText();
        objectForIntent.Details = (String)((TextView)selectedGroup.getChildAt(1)).getText();
        objectForIntent.ID = Integer.parseInt((String)((TextView)selectedGroup.getChildAt(2)).getText());
        startActivity(new Intent(GetActivity.this, activity.class).putExtra("keywords", objectForIntent.keywords)
                .putExtra("Details", objectForIntent.Details).putExtra("ID",objectForIntent.ID));
    }
```

I send the activity to be started as a parameter. But inside the `startActivity` method it says **Unknown class: activity**. So how can we pass an activity as a parameter?

Comment: May be you can send an `intent` to launch that activity as a parameter?

Comment: The syntax to launch an activity is : **startActivity(new Intent(current_activity, target_activity.class));**

Comment: @arun I am sure that I am suing that?

Comment: @S_Madushan that would have been a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `activity.getClass()` instead of `activity.class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable of the [Class type](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html). This could be passed as a parameter to a method if you wished.

```
Class clz = MyActivity.class
startActivity(new Intent(context, clz));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing a long an instance of Activity (AppCompatActivity extends Activity), you can't do `activity.class` but you can do `activity.getClass()`. Besides that, I'm assuming GetActivity is the Activity from which you want to start the new activity? You can just do `newIntent(this, activity.getClass())`.

Replace yor startActivity line with this:
`startActivity(new Intent(this, activity.getClass()).putExtra("keywords", objectForIntent.keywords)
                .putExtra("Details", objectForIntent.Details).putExtra("ID",objectForIntent.ID));`

Answer (score 0):

Just start a new intent to call your activity.

eg:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Locationdbview"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>

startActivity(new Intent(this, Locationdbview.class));
```